# Should I follow up again for my dream job?

Tags: interviewing, applications, follow-up, email-etiquette

I applied for my dream job; the job that I have wanted ever since I was a child - back in April.
These jobs come along very infrequently and this is the first time I have been appropriately qualified.

As months had passed since applying I assumed I had not gotten the job. However, on August 23rd I was sent an email from the CEO asking me to complete the first interview the next day - I of course dropped everything and made the interview. Then after a week (AUG 31) of no communication I sent a follow-up email, outlining how much I enjoyed the interview, learning more about the intricacies of the role etc. as well as offering samples of my work at my previous employer. He replied within about 15m saying that I had been selected to proceed to the final round of interviews and asked for some samples of my work. He also said that he had an incredibly busy week and would give me a timeslot for my interview "first thing next week".

It is now exactly one week since our last communication, and Tuesday (7th of Sep). Should I follow up again or will it be too much?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion GNAT. My question is more regarding the etiquette of following up a second time after the CEO's comments. Cheers though!

Answer (score 5):

> Should I follow up again or will it be too much?

Give it some time. Around here it's just turning Tuesday (00:52 to be precise) so a bit early to worry perhaps, even more considering that the CEO explicitly told you they have had an *incredibly* busy week...

It's not rare that after an incredibly busy week it follows a regularly busy week (at least). In the meantime focus on preparing for such interview, and all that they asked you for.

As always, keep your options open and only hand your notice until you are sure you landed an offer (i.e., contract).

Comment: Hi Dark! That's some good advice. I guess I'm just a bit anxious. - it's past 5pm here in Australia.

Comment: And CEOs don't normally contact interviewees. I've *met* CEOs after I've been hired, but haven't yet be contacted by one before that. This guy is already going out of his way to assure OP that they're shortlisted.